Combining XML Data to one row SSIS
Hello I have an xml file that uses the same attribute/type for multiple data elements in the same array, I can parse this data with no issues using  the zappysys  xml source and get it into columns but I want to combine all the xmltextcol rows (See sample data below)  for each XMLID into one column. Is there a way to do this with zappy sys tools or some other ssis tool? Need to do this within a dataflow task if possible.
Here is some dummy test data, the xml text data here would end up being 2 rows since there are 2 unique xmlids
Data looks something like this in the xml
<XMLREF type="XMLTextCOL" isPrimary="false" xmlid="26917204326">IT#HAWB#24433</XMLREF>
<XMLREF type="XMLTextCOL" isPrimary="false" xmlid="26917204326">IT#898591046</XMLREF>
<XMLREF type="XMLTextCOL" isPrimary="false" xmlid="26910163366">WEB4442224344</XMLREF>

So the above data I would want to end up something like
XMLTEXTCOL                   XMLID
IT#HAWB#24433 IT#898591046   26917204326
WEB4442224344                26910163366   

Here is the data as columns (note I didnt put all xml above for this data)
|XMLTEXTCOL |XMLID|
|WEB4442224344 | 26910163366|
|WEB12345 | 26878615802|
|mike@somewhere-at.com | 26921000991|
|MBL#rroogg3422 | 26921000991|
|MBL#odxy3345 | 26917204326|
|joe@somewhere.at.com | 26917204326|
|IT#444313292 | 26917204326|
|HAWB#24433 | 26917204326|
|ELG-448877 | 26916990248|
|AMS#yygg5544 | 26921000991|
|#6554321 | 26916891479|
|#555444 | 26917204326|
|#345111443 | 26889377836|
|#326655 | 26917735422|
|#1444333 | 26905908659|
|#1234 | 26922518945|
| Release No: ggttgg | 26921000991|

Thanks in Advance

I did resolve this by putting this data in a sql temp table and then doing a Stuff for the columns like
select STUFF((SELECT N’ | ’ + Value… group by id column
